# Backbone: Can't access 'this.model.*' in view

Tags: backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone and struggling with what appears to be a basic problem. I have a route set up to take in a parameter, use it to locate a model (hard-coded at this point), and render the model data in a view.

Working with a parameter of "project1", in the render function of my view I can access `this.model` and `project1.attributes` and `project1.get('name')` but I cannot access `this.model.attributes` or `this.model.get('name')` or use `this.model.toJSON()`. (Note: trying to access any of those latter ones causes the app to bomb.)

Is this a "this" bind problem? Any help is appreciated.

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "work/:project" : "project"
  },
  project: function (project) {
    $('#content').html(new ProjectView({model:project}).render().el);
  }
});

var ProjectView = Backbone.View.extend({
  id: "project",
  render: function () {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});

var Project = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var project1 = new Project({ 
  name: "Project1", 
  description : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
});
```

Comment: Why are you passing `project` as the model for `ProjectView`? This is a route param, not an actual Backbone model.

Comment: The parameter is also the name of a model. My thinking is when a user visits '/work/project1', the param 'project1' is passed to `ProjectView` as the model name, and then that model (see it at bottom of my code) is accessed and displayed in the view. Does that not make sense?

Comment: I think the actual model has to be passed to the view and not some `param` which has the same name as the model.

Comment: Even if I don't pass the param name to `ProjectView` as the model name and instead set the model name inside `ProjectView` as `model: "project1"`, I still can't access `this.model.get("name")`, etc.

Comment: Can you try `new ProjectView({model:project1})`? This is what I meant by passing the model itself.

Comment: You're passing strings, not models.

Comment: @AmulyaKhare - If I make that change, my route fails (URL not found). Also, see my response to the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have already mentioned, your basic problem is that you're passing a string to a View, but that View is expecting a Model.  This line:

```
$('#content').html(new ProjectView({model:project}).render().el);
```

Is the problem: `project` needs to be an instance of `Backbone.Model`, but it's not.  That line should instead look something like this:

```
var project1 = new Project({ 
    name: "Project1", 
    description : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
});
$('#content').html(new ProjectView({model: project1}).render().el);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I modify my code as you recommend by moving the new model creation inside the `project: function` and passing the new model name "project1" instead of the route parameter, my route fails (URL not found).

Comment: Can't say for sure, but it sounds to me like I (and by "I" I really mean all of the commentors) solved your initial bug, and now that it's resolved you're hitting a new problem in your code.  We'll need to see more details of that problem, but I'd recommend starting a new SO thread for them: otherwise this thread will essentially have two questions in it, your original and the new one, plus a super-long comments thread, and answers which may apply to one or both of your questions (so doing two separate posts will be much cleaner).

Comment: P.S. Just in case the two questions thing wasn't clear, what I meant was that your original question was "why can't I access this.model", and the answer was that `this.model` was a string not a model, and that's why you can't access it.  Asking about any other topic (eg. "why am I getting this routing error that has nothing to do with me passing a string in for a model") will muddle what this thread is about (and starting a new thread takes like ten seconds anyway).

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks, again.